# В методе postProcessBeforeInitialization не доступны собственные аннотации

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-boot, аннотации

Пытаюсь реализовать свою собственную аннотацию.

Основная логика будет в `postProcessAfterInitialization`
Для того чтобы определить аннотированные бины, реализовал `postProcessBeforeInitialization` так:

```
private val map = mutableMapOf<String, Class<Any>>()

override fun postProcessBeforeInitialization(bean: Any, beanName: String): Any? {
    val beanClass = bean.javaClass
    if (beanClass.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation::class.java)) {
        map[beanName] = beanClass
    }
    return bean
}
```

Проблема в том, что по задумке моя аннотация должна ставиться над main-классом, который в свою очередь аннотирован `@SpringBootAnnotation` и видимо из-за этого в методе `postProcessBeforeInitialization` мне в качестве бина приходит уже прокси, а не оригинальный класс.

Соответсвенно прокси аннотирована только аннотацией `@SpringBootAnnotation`, моей аннотации над прокси-классом нет, мой вопрос - можно ли как-то получить оригинал класса, который аннотирован с помощью `@SpringBootAnnotation` ?

Знаю, что можно получить оригинальный класс из прокси с помощью `bean.javaClass.superclass` но не уверен, что это очень хорошее решение

Comment: там под ответом комментарии почитайте потом, если интересно

Answer (score 1):

Аннотация потерялась не из-за прокси.
Это не является причиной того, что вы не можете ее найти во время выполнения программы.

## В чем причина?

Все дело в стратегии хранения аннотаций.

---

Всего есть три стратегии:

**CLASS**
Аннотации записываются в файл класса(`.class`) компилятором, но не доступны во время выполнения виртуальной машине.

**RUNTIME**
Аннотации записываются в файл класса(`.class`) компилятором и доступны во время выполнения, а также доступны для рефлексии.

**SOURCE**
Аннотации исключаются во время компиляции и не попадают в файл класса(`.class`). Соответственно они не доступны во время выполнения.

---

Значением по умолчанию является `CLASS`, что значит что по умолчанию аннотация не доступны во время выполнения.

## Что делать?

Для того, чтобы сделать ее доступной и иметь возможность читать ее с помощью рефлексии, необходимо изменить стратегию хранения.

Сделать это можно проставив аннотацию `Retention` со значением `RUNTIME` над Вашей аннотацией

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) 
//ниже объявление вашей аннотации
```

Comment: Да я знаю про это, она как раз и стоит у меня как RUNTIME, но в прокси ее все равно нет

Comment: @NpB, ок. Я вечером еще соберу тестовый проект, подходящий ваших условиям и посмотрю, что там может быть не так. Я когда реализовывал BeanPostProcessor'ы у меня только в этом проблема была.

Comment: Возможно есть разница в версии спринг бута, если что я использую spring boot 2.6.1

Comment: @NpB, Я потестировал и вот с чем столкнулся `Bean 'application' of type [pro.reprov.Application] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)`

Comment: Есть такая штука как `BeanPostProcessorChecker`, которая проверяет может ли иметь доступ тот или иной пост процессор к бину. В частности если бин инфрастуктурный ( `this.isInfrastructureBean(beanName)` ), то у Вашего бинПостПроцессора не будет доступа к этому бину.  Справедливости  ради скажу что данную проверку я нашел только в `postProcessAfterInitialization`.

Comment: Более того, я попытался  просканировать все бины и не смог найти бин с аннотацией `@SpringBootApplication` ни в before, ни в after...правда я пробовал на `2.4.3`, который под рукой был. Чуть позже попробую на `2.6.1`

Comment: плюс ряд компонентов исходя из жизненного цикла контекста настраиваются до `FactoryBean` и не попадают под обработку `BeanPostProcessor`ов

Comment: на данный момент я бы и от прокси не отказался, только вот не дает никто)

Comment: еще мне интересно для какой именно задачи требуется аннотация именно над main классом? разве нельзя ту же задачу решить иначе? я пока даже придумать не могу для чего мне такое может понадобиться. вы уверены что у вас с композицией в приложении все в порядке?

Comment: @NpB, попытался вытащить бин main class'а не через `BeanPostProcessor`, а через `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` (она отрабатывает до `BeanPostProcessor`). И там мне удалось вытащить и бин аппликейшена(пусть и прокси) и свою кастомную аннотацию(она у прокси была и должна была быть, поэтому я изначально и говорил что не в прокси дело).

Comment: Если хотите, могу потом все изыскания и примеры свои в ответ добавить

Comment: Спасибо, думаю будет полезно, если добавите примеры в ответ